# C++ access to public variables in virtual method

Tags: c++, class, virtual, abstract-class

In c++ I have an Abstract class A:

```
 class A
 {
 public:
    A(){}
    virtual ~A(){}
    virtual void out(std::ofstream& outFile) = 0;
    virtual void in(std::ifstream& inFile) = 0;
};
```

And B class in which I want to use virtual methods:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
   B();              
   double angle;
   int index;


   virtual void out(std::ofstream& outFile);
   virtual void in(std::ifstream& inFile);

};
```

Now here is a question: I want to use B class variable like (int index) in virtual methods:

```
virtual void out(std::ofstrea& outFile)
{
    outFile<< index << angle;       
}
```

Here I get compiler error that angle and index are not declared in this scope. It is somewhat logical because this variables are not declared in class A.
Now how can I get access to variable angle and index in virtual methods?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're implementing the method outside the class, you don't mark it as `virtual` and you qualify its name:

```
void B::out(std::ofstrea& outFile)
{
    outFile<< index << angle;       
}
```

Comment: Oh, What a ridiculous missing.

Answer (score 1):

When defining your functions out of line you want to use something like this:

```
void B::out(std::ofstream& outFile)
{
    outFile<< index << angle;       
}
```

Any member of the respective class is accessible in a member function, independent of whether the function is virtual or not.

Since talking about functions reading or writing data: Unless you really need to make use of specific details of `std::ofstream` or `std::ifstream`, e.g., use `open()`, you should probably pass `std::ostream` or `std::istream` references. This way the functions can also be used with different stream stream types, e.g., `std::ostringstream` and `std::istringstream`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have written your function body in the class declaration, you must prefix the member function name with the class name:

```
void B::out(std::ofstream& out)
{
   out << index << angle;
}
```

What exact error did you get by the way, this would be much simpler if you could post the exact error code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the class name before member function definition.

```
void B::out(std::ofstrea& outFile)  // Virtual keyword is optional in defintion.
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Surely 'virtual' is in fact illegal unless it's a declaration as well (ie inline)?

Comment: There is nothing illegal about it. You can specify the `virtual` keyword in member function definition as well.

Comment: @Mahesh Hmm... I just checked. G++ gives an error: "error: 'virtual' outside class declaration"

Answer (score 0):

When you define a class method in your cpp file you must give the class name as scope like this :

```
void B::out(std::ofstrea& outFile)
{
outFile<< index << angle;       
}
```